# How can i resolve this error NullPointerException Spinner-ArrayAdapter

Tags: java, android

I am getting a `NullPointerException` when i am trying to set an adapter to a spinner, here is the bugging  part  of the code, please i will appreciate your help thank you.
`mDeptDom` is an object list which contains String and `List<String>` as value and everytime I set the `ArrayAdapter` to another spinner I get the famous `NullPointerException`

```
mDeptDom = deptDomDao.findAll();
    List<String> nomDept = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < mDeptDom.size(); i++) {
        nomDept.add(mDeptDom.get(i).getNom());
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> deptAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>        (this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, nomDept);
        deptAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spDepartementDom.setAdapter(deptAdapter);
    spDepartementExp.setAdapter(deptAdapter);

    spDepartementDom.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {

            dept = arg0.getSelectedItem().toString();


            for(int i=0;i<mDeptDom.size();i++){
             if(mDeptDom.get(i).getNom().equalsIgnoreCase(dept)){
                mVilleC= mDeptDom.get(i).getListVille();
                break;
             }
            }

            List<String> mNomVilleC=new ArrayList<String>();

            for(int i=0;i<mVilleC.size();i++){
                mNomVilleC.add(mVilleC.get(i).getNomV());

            }

           // System.out.println(" BoooM " + mNomVilleC);
            /*ArrayAdapter<String> nomVilleAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, mNomVilleC);
            nomVilleAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spVilleDom.setAdapter(nomVilleAdapter);  */


        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        }

    });
```

Comment: Which line throws the exception?

Comment: the commented lines ' 
             ArrayAdapter<String> nomVilleAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, mNomVilleC);
            nomVilleAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spVilleDom.setAdapter(nomVilleAdapter);  '

Comment: Which one?  Your stack trace tells you this.

Comment: Stack trace just prints, package.ActivityClass.onItemSelected, fireOnSelected, i meant logCat

Comment: but when i comment the code added before, everything is ok,but spinner is populated from the xml file, i want to do it with the arrayAdapter

Comment: What, no line numbers in the stack trace?

Comment: sorry i am new to eclipse, are we talking about the column with the PID label if so the number is 3526

Comment: AdapterView.java: 871

Comment: Eureka, it was about a non-inflated widget, thank you